# Laser Scanner Merging in one Topic

Tags: navigation, laser, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

Hello,

I am working on the package for merging multiple laser scanner data in one topic (Ira Laser Tools). I am getting 2 data from different sensors placed one on the front of the robot and one on the rare (scan1 and scan2), Then i apply the multi merger node to merge to get one laser scan data (scan), but it is always empty and giving me the following warning

**[ WARN] [1467292029.145711135]: Transformer::setExtrapolationLimit is deprecated and does not do anything**

I created in my URDF model a virtual laser which is my destination frame_id (in green in the picture), it is placed at the midpoint of the rare and front lasers.

Note that in the picture the data in red are the data received from scan1 and scan2 respectively.

Please find in the attached file above a screen shoot that describes the situation. And please note than the scan topic is empty.

Is there any way to solve this problem please? i would be really thankful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238531/laser-scanner-merging-in-one-topic/) by [wassimhariri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26309/wassimhariri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-06-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on 2016-11-10**:
Hi,wassimhariri

I have the same question ,as the warn `[ WARN] [1467292029.145711135]: Transformer::setExtrapolationLimit is deprecated and does not do anything`

This problem solved ? If settled, please share to me, thank you!

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-11-11**:
I think the warning should nt be the reason why there is no scan in the merged topic. Are you sure the 2 laser scan topic are called "scan1" and "scan2"? Can you post the output of "rostopic info /scan1" and "rostopic info /scan2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

actually this problem was solved, we created another package than ira laser tools called scan merger, where i can get 3 different scan data from 3 different laser scanners and then publish them on one scan topic where navigation can accept it and implement SLAM. i will post details as an answer

---

Originally posted by [wassimhariri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26309/wassimhariri/) with karma: 70 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-12-02**:
Any detail update :) ?

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2016-12-16**:
Yes, details would be welcomed :)

**Comment by [Chaos Jin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29445/chaos-jin/) on 2017-02-22**:
I have the same problem. Would you please show us how to slove this problem? Thank you!

**Comment by [Orl](https://answers.ros.org/users/38968/orl/) on 2022-06-22**:
Where is this scan merger package ?